# argparse library conflict between Django and Google Cloud SDK - how to resolve

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, pycharm

I am trying to run my Django app in PyCharm and getting the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_abbrev'
```

(This only occurs when I run it from the 'Run' menu in PyCharm, not from the terminal).

The error comes from `django.core.management.base.py`. The `CommandParser` class in there inherits from `ArgumentParser`, but the interpreter is mixing up the standard `from argparse import ArgumentParser`, which does have the keyword argument `allow_abbrev`, with the `ArgumentParser` in the Google Cloud SDK, which doesn't have the argument `allow_abbrev`.

The Google Cloud SDK `ArgumentParser` that the interpreter is referencing isn't even in my project directory.

I believe this only started when I upgraded the Google Cloud SDK tools.

I am running a virtual environment with a recent version of Python but I am confused as to how it is picking up Google's `ArgumentParser` instead of the one Django is expecting.

I don't really know how to reproduce this, but it is some kind of PyCharm-Django-Google issue that arises from the below:

- Set up a run configuration in PyCharm to run 'python manage.py runserver' with a Python 3 venv interpreter
- Have the latest Google Cloud SDK tools installed

Most likely something weird in the PyCharm run configuration, as it runs fine from the terminal as I said.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It seems like this is a known error regarding the `argparse` library. Please take into consideration the following GitHub issues. [Issue 1](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq/issues/47), [Issue 2](https://github.com/bharadwaj-raju/TextSuggest/issues/47) and as well as that [link](https://python.developreference.com/article/10009506/Django-admin+TypeError%3A+__init__()+got+an+unexpected+keyword+argument+'allow_abbrev').

Comment: @tzovourn Yes, I've done some research and have seen others say that Python version needs to be >= 3.5. My venv Python runtime is greater than 3.5 so `allow_abbrev` should be supported. It's Google's weird library that doesn't support `allow_abbrev` and that's causing the conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I deleted the `.idea` folder in PyCharm and reopened the project. PyCharm recreated the folder and the app finally ran without issue. So it looks like it was a PyCharm configuration issue, but nothing obvious that I could see on the surface.